# mvn gitflow:release-finish with main-branch

Tags: maven, git-flow

I'm getting the following errormessage:

```
Failed to execute goal com.amashchenko.maven.plugin:gitflow-maven-plugin:1.18.0:release-finish (default-cli) on project parent: release-finish: error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

That's because the branch is called main instead of master.
Renaming the branch to master is not an option.

Is there any way to pass the information about the main-branch to the maven-gitflow-plugin?

As stated in the errormessage I'm using the plugin version 1.18.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is configurable in the gitflow-maven-plugin configuration:

```
<gitFlowConfig>
    <productionBranch>main</productionBranch>
</gitFlowConfig>
```

Comment: You're right. The solution can also be found [here on github](https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin#github-flow). 
to bad I was only looking for a solution in the [documentation of the release-finish-mojo](https://aleksandr-m.github.io/gitflow-maven-plugin/release-finish-mojo.html)